# How to create sources jars for java_library in bazel

Tags: bazel

As part of our efforts to create a bazel-maven transition interop tool (that creates maven sized jars from more granular sized bazel jars) there is a need to create sources jars.

For `java_binary` targets there is a mechanism to create it using `-src.jar` suffix

e.g., for a `java_binary` target called `foo`, run `bazel build //:foo-src.jar`

But, using the same mechanism for `java_library` target named `bar` I get:

`ERROR: no such target '//:bar-src.jar': target 'bar-src.jar' not declared in package '' (did you mean 'libbar-src.jar'?) defined by /Users/.../java_project/BUILD.`

Is there a another mechanism for `java_library`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As indicated by the error, the source target is called `//:libbar-src.jar` (with the `lib` prefix). See the list of [outputs of java_library](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/java.html#java_library) for reference.

Comment: My bad for missing the error message meaning. Maybe instead of 'did you mean', the error could say 'try'...